# How can I find common parts of 3 or more strings?

Tags: javascript, python, algorithm, difference

**Backgound (simplified)**

I´ve got a lot of files that where auto-generated by a 3rd party (think the output of several different address merges) and I´m trying to programmatically restore the original templates and address/custom data from it.

**What I´ve looked at so far**

There are plenty of libraries (jsdiff, difflib) to diff two files. I´ve found it helpful to do so to figure out the % words changed - which is a good indication if two files are from the same template

**Question**

So, now I´m at the stage of having grouped together similar text files, now I´d ideally find a way to diff all of those, separating identical text from the differences:

```
Hello [Mr, Mrs] [NameA, NameB, NameC...], we are pleased to (...)
```

So, how can I find common parts of 3 or more strings in Javascript/Python?

Comment: @DomTomCat I think your (deleted) answer could be read as, "No, there isn't, but you can use a wrapper and a non-standard delta to do it with difflib." Thomas, that's probably the best answer you can expect; sometimes things don't exist yet.

Comment: What do you want to do that you can't use difflib etc. for?

Comment: @Kittsil I´m an optimist... Someone surely has solved that before... :)

Comment: @HåkenLid well, a n-file diff... Using a 2-file diff library to generate a n-file diff isn´t that trivial...

Comment: @thomasf1 Not everything has, though. It's been done in vim, but maybe not yet in js or python. They are newer languages, after all. But you could do it and put it on github. ;-)

Comment: i don't get it. if you have a diff, what's the problem? anything that doesn't change among two (or more) instances of a template will the the template itself. find one that spits out html, remove() the red/green tags (keeping the slots if desired), and keep the rest. also, how many is "a lot"?

Answer (score 2):

I think you need a suffix tree ([wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree)).
Build the suffix tree for each document. If you don't care about individual characters feel free to use words instead of characters.

Once you have this, you need to find the longest path from the root that is found in all (or most) of the individual suffix trees. So just pick one, get the root of all nodes and do a DFS, going down a link only if you find it in all (or sufficiently many) trees. This will iterate through all sub-strings that are common in all the documents.

Not sure if there's a lib that does all this already, but there should be something already to help you build the suffix tree.